# Using mock to patch a non-existing attribute

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking, pytest

I'm trying to test a context manager that makes use of a class that uses some `__getattr__` magic to resolve several attributes which don't actually exist on the class.  I'm running into a problem where mock is raising an AttributeError when trying to patch the class.

Simplified example of objects I want to patch.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr == 'myfunc':
            return lambda:return None
        raise AttributeError('error')


class MyContextManager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyContextManager, self).__init__()
        self.myclass = MyClass()

    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.myclass.myfunc()
```

Test code

```
def test_MyContextManager():
    with patch.object(MyClass, 'myfunc', return_value=None) as mock_obj:
        with MyContextManager():
             pass

    # Do some tests on mock object
```

Here is the error I get:

```
AttributeError: <class 'MyClass'> does not have the attribute 'myfunc'
```

I'm able to do this and run the test, but it doesn't restore the attribute (or simply remove the mock attribute in this case) automatically:

```
MyClass.myfunc= Mock(return_value=None)
```

I'm open to using another library besides mock to achieve this.  I'm also using pytest.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To use [patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) in these kind of tests you should use `create` parameter that will force to create the attribute if not exist.

So your test should do something like this:

```
def test_MyContextManager():
    with patch.object(MyClass, 'myfunc', create=True, return_value=None) as mock_obj:
        with MyContextManager():
             pass
```